Store a range of cells to an array that will later be exported as table to powerpoint
I have these two for loops that are trying to create slides for a powerpoint presentation but one is suppose to find and store specific ranges of cells that are referencing a PivotTable
This one is trying to find the ranges of the tables in the excel file in one worksheet and actually store them in an array of 40 elements (redim RngGroup(1 to 40))
'Find table range
For Each foundCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    
    If Not IsEmpty(foundCell) Then
        control = foundCell.Value
        
        If control = "Values" Then
            stRow = foundCell.Row
        End If
        
        If control = "Grand Total" Then
            endRow = foundCell.Row
        Else
            GoTo Line1
        End If
    Else
        GoTo Line1
    End If
    
    Set RngGroup(i) = Range(Cells(stRow, 1), Cells(endRow, 5))
    i = i + 1
    
Line1:
Next foundCell

And this one trying to create slides for the Tables and charts
For Each Chrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            
    'Adding slide for table
    Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(SIndex, ppLayoutCustom)
    
    Set TbRange = RngGroup(i)
    TbRange.Copy
    PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
    i = i + 1
    'Copy chart
    Chrt.Copy
    
    'Create slide, set layout to custom
    Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(SIndex + 1, ppLayoutCustom)
        PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
    
    'Increment index value
    SIndex = SIndex + 2
Next Chrt


The first bit of code is creating an array of ranges to use in the second bit of code. What part isn't working?

May "Values" string be found in any cell of the used range? I have some doubts, but I cannot be sure about that... If they can be found in a single column your code will be much faster than iterating only on the respective column. To be even faster you can place that column in an array. Then, as stated in the above comment, you loaded an array of ranges. It can be handled but with some difficulties. A Union range looks more suitable. Why array of 40 elements? Do you know the occurrences number? If more, the code will raise an error. If less, you need to ReDim Preserve it...

@PeterT The part (TbRange.Copy) where it is suppose to copy the cells in that element it keeps saying "Object variable or With block variable not set"

@FaneDuru is it possible to create a dynamic array of unknown size and also yes it is slow now I only need to check the A and D columns

Check that the array holds a valid range with Debug.Print RngGroup(i).Address. You may get an error there too, if that element of the array is not a Range.

Also, you can use a Collection instead of an array if you don't know how many items you need.

@PeterT Yes I got an error so if its not a Range what did I assign in that location

@PeterT Okay Thanks I'll try that to limit space loading

It's not clear from your code that the two snippets are from a single function or (at least) two functions. It would help if you can post either your full code or a complete-enough example to see the code and variables in context. Also, you may have a problem with which worksheet your Range is coming from when it's assigned. See this site for more information.

Why to have errors when correctly set a range? On which row does the mentioned error rase and in which context? So, should we understand that the searched strings "Values" and "Grand Total" may be in any of the two mentioned columns? Then, don't you need a header for the table you want populating? If so, where from to be taken?

In order to receive more help you must help  us understanding what you try accomplishing... Do you want creating a table in a PP slide, containing all values collected in RngGroup array? Or one table for each range loaded in RngGroup array? If this second option, should all mentioned tables be created in the same slide? Is any relation between the mentioned charts and the required tables? Do you need creating tables or pasting ranges? Do you understand the difference between the two objects? Are there (already) charts to iterate between them?

@FaneDuru What I am trying to implement is to copy a table from an excel sheet as it is because it contains some formats that must go along with it, I don't just want to export the data from the Excel file to the powerpoint presentation

So the table is alreading in Excel and the search string are the fixed terms found at the first and last row respectively, so if see my algorithm all I'm doing is to actually find the row positions of those terms and then use them to create ranges for those tables because there's multiple tables with similar format and data that are in the same worksheet and I must extract them all at once.

I cannot understand anything from your last comment... How having "a table from an excel sheet" and also "there's multiple tables with similar format and data"? Supposing that the first comment was wrong and you have many tables, are they situated one on top of the other and have the markers in the same two mentioned columns? Then, if they are different tables, why not exporting the tables as they are and extract their range? Do you have the marker "Values" on the tables header?

@FaneDuru Okay so these tables are on the same worksheet, now not on top of each other but they the reason being that I opted to extract ranges rather than export them is because they are PivotTables and I haven't found a way to export them, what I really need is to be able to export multiple PivotTables in one worksheet as they are like you would do with Charts also the string "Values" is on the first row of the table I'm using that to ignore all other unnecessary cells just include those that are spanning from the top row which has the string and limiting to the row containing "Grand Total"

Does, at least, one of the mentioned tables have the markers on columns A:A or D:D? If so, are they exactly as you wrote ("Values" and "Grand Total")? Did you insert the debugging code line as I suggested? If so, what did it return? If not, why not? How to be helped if you do not clarify what you try doing against what you have? If tables are not on top of the other, why did you use a range composed of A:E columns slices? Only to confuse us? Did you find those pieces of code somewhere and you thought that they will maybe work? Do you think we here are bored and needing some work?

Did you read the assumptions I wrote on top of my answer? If so, why don't you refer to them? Mainly, the first one which is based on your statemen in a comment...

You did not answer my clarifications comment... So, the next code assumes that the two searched strings exist in columns A:A or D:D, the code will set the active PowerPoint prsentation, inserts a new slide (after the last existing), create a shape and process the array in its table. Prior to that, it writes the table header:
Sub PlaceRangesArrayInTable()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr() As Range, arrAD, stRow As Long, iRow As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, r As Long, h As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arrAD = sh.Range("A1:D" & lastR).Value2 ' it assumes that in the first row there are headers
  
  ReDim arr(lastR / 2) 'maximum possible number of elements...
  For i = 2 To UBound(arrAD) 'place the necessary ranges in an array
    If arrAD(i, 1) = "Values" Or arrAD(i, 4) = "Values" Then stRow = i
        
     If arrAD(i, 1) = "Grand Total" Or arrAD(i, 4) = "Grand Total" Then
        Set arr(k) = sh.Range("A" & stRow, "E" & i)
        iRow = iRow + arr(k).rows.count: k = k + 1
     End If
  Next i
  
  ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1) 'keep only elements containing ranges

  'Now PowerPoint part:_________________________________________________________________
   'Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application, ps As PowerPoint.Presentation, mySlide As PowerPoint.slide, myShape As PowerPoint.Shape
   Dim ppt As Object, ps As Object, mySlide As Object, myShape As Object
   
   Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.application") 'get existing PowerPoint session
                                                   'you can create a new one if necessary
   Set ps = ppt.ActivePresentation 'set active presentation as the one to process on
   Set mySlide = ps.Slides.Add(ps.Slides.count + 1, 12) 'ppLayoutBlank (insert a blank slide as last)
   
   'add the necessary Table:
   Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes.AddTable(iRow + 1, 5) '+ 1 for the table header
   
   With myShape.table
       'create the header:
       For h = 1 To 5: .Cell(1, h).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = "Col" & h: Next h
       For k = 0 To UBound(arr) 'Iterate between the array ranges:
            For i = 1 To arr(k).rows.count        'iterate between the range rows
                For j = 1 To arr(k).Columns.count 'iterate between the range columns
                    'copy  values in the table:
                    .Cell(i + r + 1, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = _
                        arr(k).cells(i, j).text
                Next
            Next
            r = r + arr(k).rows.count
        Next k
    End With
   mySlide.Select 'activate the new inserted slide
   AppActivate ppt.ActiveWindow.Caption 'activate PowerPoint
   '___________________________________________________________________________________
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
Edited:
Please, test the next version able to copy all existing tables (ListObjects):
Sub PlaceTablesInArray_CopyToPP()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr(), i As Long, j As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  ReDim arr(sh.ListObjects.count - 1)
  For i = 1 To sh.ListObjects.count
    Set arr(i - 1) = sh.ListObjects(i)
  Next i
  
  'PowerPoint prodessing part:
  'Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application, ps As PowerPoint.Presentation, mySlide As PowerPoint.slide, shp As PowerPoint.Shape
  Dim ppt As Object, ps As Object, mySlide As Object, shp As Object
  Const shTop As Single = 20: Dim shLeft As Single: shLeft = 20
  
  
  Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.application") 'get existing PowerPoint session
                                                  'you can create a new one if necessary
   Set ps = ppt.ActivePresentation 'set active presentation as the one to process on
   Set mySlide = ps.Slides.Add(ps.Slides.count + 1, 12) 'ppLayoutBlank (insert a blank slide as last)
   mySlide.Select 'to paste in the active slide (ExecuteMso)
   For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
      arr(i).Range.Copy

      ppt.ActivePresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
      Set shp = mySlide.Shapes(i + 1)
      'you can arrange their position in a different way...
      shp.top = shTop
      shp.left = shLeft: shLeft = shLeft + shp.width + 2
   Next i
   
   'Activate the processed new slide:
   AppActivate ppt.ActiveWindow.Caption
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

So I did test it and it seems to be creating a table header and stops there without exporting the rest of the data

@Leonardo Hobeni I tested the above code and it works as it should. I am afraid that you do not have "Values" and "Grand Total" on the mentioned columns ("A:A" or "D:D"). Try inserting the next code line Debug.Print k: Stop above ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1). What does it show in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G`, being in VBE) when code stops there?

@Leonardo Please, test the new version (after Edited:) and send some feedback. If you know what an Excel Table means, it will copy all existing tables from the active sheet in a new added sheet of the active presentation.

Sorry I was not able to respond in time, so I just checked it works better but I opted to use collection for a dynamic sizing

@Leonardo Hobeni I cannot get you but never mind. I can live with that... I only tried helping.
